# Tool to create HTML slideshows/presentations

Tags: html, presentations

I've seen somewhere a presentation that was written entirely in HTML, CSS and Javascript.  It was "properly" structured, so that if you'd view it with Lynx it would look like a normal document, yet in Firefox (and others, I suppose) it looked like a Powerpoint presentation, with added "back" and "forward" buttons.

Does anyone know what tool can be used to create such presentations?  Or where I can find examples of such presentations on the web?  Google fails me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you saw something done with [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/s5-intro.html).